# Can you Install docker on a virtual server?

Tags: docker, vmware, devops, private-cloud

The company I work for has a completely virtualized data center (DC) and is looking to even move to a cloud based DC. The DC runs on VMware vSpere. However, the development team is making plans to introduce Docker. I'm hoping these 2 can work together as they would both make some really good improvements to both teams.

**My question now is, can docker run on top of Virtual Servers (Machines) without any problems or does it strictly have to be installed on bare-metal OS(s)??**

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Better to try the option before posting the question

Answer (score 0):

> My question now is, can docker run on top of Virtual Servers (Machines)

absolutely, yes!

i do this all the time... in Digital Ocean VPS servers, in Linux and Windows virtual machines in Parallels on my mac, in RedHat linux on a VMWare infrastructure for a client, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** Docker can run on top of Virtual Servers.

> But if you are moving to Cloud and choosing AWS then you can try spot instances as there are many other best options to save money and time because docker in a virtual environment will make your Infrastructure/Network more complex. You have to manage 2 different types of networking topology, which means within the VPC and inside the Instances.